# How to activate hardware accelerated video decoding. VA-API in Chromium-based browser

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, chromium, vaapi

I am currently trying to run Stadia 4K gameplay in Ubuntu 20.04, which demands VP9 hardware accelerated decoding.

So far, I've tried both Brave and Chromium with hardware acceleration enabled, and I tried this tutorial: [How To Enable Hardware Acceleration In Chromium On Ubuntu Or Linux Mint](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/08/how-to-enable-hardware-accelerated.html?m=1) for installing a VA-API patched PPA build enabling hardware acceleration in Ubuntu, without success.

My current system configuration is:

```
Computer: Dell Latitude 5490
Distro: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
CPU: Intel i7-8650U (4.2 GHz)
GPU: Nvidia GeForce MX130
GPU: Intel UHD Graphics 620
Graphics driver: nvidia-driver-440
```

Apparently, hardware acceleration does not work with Nvidia GPUs, but should work with Intel integrated GPU. However, selecting Intel GPU in Nvidia X Server settings, does not make hardware acceleration work as it should. It also made my system very slow and choppy when I use an external monitor.

How can I set up hardware acceleration correctly?

Output from running `vdpauinfo` returns the following:

```bsh
display: :1   screen: 0
GPU at BusId 0x3 doesn't have a supported video decoder
Error creating VDPAU device: 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps I took to run Stadia 4K gameplay in Ubuntu 20 in Chrome (maybe it works in Chromium too):

1. Install the latest video card driver. For the NVIDIA cards, go to "Software & Updates" => "Additional Drivers" tab => choose the latest driver. Probably it's the same for Radeon.
2. Install [Stadia+ Chrome addon](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stadia%20-extension/bbhmnnecicphphjamhdefpagipoegijd?hl=en).
3. Restart the browser.
4. Before opening any games in Stadia, press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>, a panel will appear on the right side, choose VP9 and 4k.

Comment: Easy as that. =) I can confirm this works in Brave as well. Does this force hardware acceleration though?

Comment: This does nothing for hardware decoding.

Comment: This actually explains how to enable hardware accelerated video decoding in Chromium-based browsers: https://www.linuxuprising.com/2021/01/how-to-enable-hardware-accelerated.html