# webgl low performances under nvidia

Tags: nvidia, webgl

I have a Dell XPS 15 under Ubuntu 20.04 with an Intel UHD 630 and Nvidia GTX 1050 configured in "on-demand" mode. In gaming it works properly.
However when I use Firefox to load [this demo](https://webglsamples.org/aquarium/aquarium.html) under the Intel GPU, I can display up to 1000 fishes at 60FPS. Under the Nvidia GPU, it fluctuates between 20 and 30FPS, even with one fish.
Under chromuim-based browser it's worse and limited at 15FPS.

Thanks by advance for your answers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to activate hardware accelerated video decoding. VA-API in Chromium-based browser](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1257647/how-to-activate-hardware-accelerated-video-decoding-va-api-in-chromium-based-br) see also last comment below answer.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably, your browser is set not to use hardware acceleration. In Chrome navigate to *Menu → Settings → Advanced → System* and switch on *Use hardware acceleration when available.*

Answer (score 1):

You're right, gpu acceleration is disabled under on-demand mode, in both web-base (chromium and firefox). It's probably due to an incompatibility. If I run all the system under the Nvidia GPU (performance mode), then the GPU acceleration is enabled and I can go up to 15000 fishes at 60FPS .
So now I know that WebGL doesn't support Nvidia Prime on-demand mode.

However I'll go back to on-demand mode because the laptop is noisy and the battery doesn't hold charge for a long time in performance mode. For many WebGL apps, the Intel GPU is enough.

Thanks for your answer